# Adding subscription for Custom Objects - Commercetool

Tags: commercetools

I am trying to add a subscription for custom objects in commerce tool. I am using the following definition:

```json
{
  "destination": {
    "type": "AzureServiceBus",
    "connectionString": "**********************"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "resourceTypeId": "key-value-document",
      "types": []
    }
  ],
  "key": "customeobj"
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> The resource type ID 'key-value-document' is unknown or not supported by messages subscriptions. These resource type IDs are supported: review, cart, payment, order, customer, category, inventory-entry, product, customer-group, store, product-type, product-selection.

It would be great if someone knows what to do about this.

Comment: Found the answer - we can listen for change  instead of "messages" we can use changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, message subscriptions are only supported for messages on order, product, category, payment, customer, review, inventory entry and store at the moment.
Change subscriptions support the resource type key-value-document if that is sufficient for your use case.